# Retrieve same number of records in an ID IN query even with a duplicate

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I'm using PostgreSQL. If I have an **id in** query say:

```
select * from public.record where id in (1,5,1);
```

this will only give me two rows, because the id 1 has a duplicate. But what if I want to display a set of records containing :

```
id | value
1  |   A
5  |   B
1  |   A
```

Regardless of the reason why I would do this, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by joining the values:

```
with ids (id) as (
  values (1),(5),(1)
) 
select r.*
from public.record r
  join ids on r.id = ids.id;
```

If you need to keep the order of the parameter list, you need to add a column to sort on:

```
with ids (id, sort_order) as (
  values 
      (1, 1),
      (5, 2),
      (1, 1)
) 
select r.*
from public.record r
  join ids on r.id = ids.id
order by ids.sort_order;
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it allowed me to insert the ids in easier with not so much string manipulation unlike the other answer..nevertheless i upvoted both..thanks

Comment: just a follow up if you may, how do I separate a string of ids such as "1,5,1" to something enclosed in parenthesis in "(1),(5),(1)" in php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` on a subquery:

```
SELECT
    r.id, r.value
FROM public.record r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id
) t
    ON t.id = r.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If requirement is to have all rows (1,5,1) in the result set including not matching public.record then use OUTER join

```
with c(id) as (
  values (1),(5),(1)
) 
select r.*
from c  
left join public.record pr
on pr.id = c.id;
```

**EDIT**
And if the input is a string kind of '1,5,1' sql injection safe code should use it as a parameter, not code.

```
declare @prm varchar(1000) ='1,5,1'; 

select r.*
from  DelimitedSplit8K(@prm) c 
left join public.record pr
on pr.id = cast(c.item as int);
```

Where DelimitedSplit8K is Jeff Moden's function (MS SQL) http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ or any other splitter you choose.

Comment: how do I separate a string of ids such as "1,5,1" to something enclosed in parenthesis in "(1),(5),(1)" in php.

Comment: @muffin You may split the delimited string in Sql as well. See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/   Fig. 21 shows the code, it runs fast.